# Self executing function with internal functions scope issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a simple function with two sub functions internally. I run into couple of issues **only** when I've deployed on to server(minified). locally everything works as expected.

**Snippet:**

```
 var myFun = function() {
   const one = function() {
       return false;
     },
     two = function() {
       console.log(!one()); 
     };
   return {
     One: one,
     Two: two
   }
 }()
```

**Issue 1:** **!** not operator inside function **two** throws me error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 't' has already been declared" when i try write `one() == true` its works fine

**Issue 2:** `one()` inside function **two** throws me undefined for some unknown reason which makes me add *typeOf* check

Minified version:

```js
(tt(!0),!1):!0})},cu=function(){var n,t;gt("");typeof ft()[0]!="undefined"&&ft().length>0&&(n=ft()[0].EmailAddress().replace(/.*@/,""),ccEmailDomains&&(t=";",ccEmailDomains.indexOf(",")>-1&&(t=","),n+=t+ccEmailDomains),gt(n))},lu=function(n){var t=[];return $.each(n,function(n,i)
```

Comment: I think the minification method is relevant here, so if you can share more about that would be good

Comment: @FabianLauer we bundle & minify using .net mvc .

Comment: Can you please provide the output of the minified file.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan added original minified version related to the scenario explained above. not sure if that helps.

Comment: @supercool Can you try this

(function myFun() {
   function one() {
       return false;
     };
     function two() {
       console.log(!this.one()); 
     };
   return {
     One: one,
     Two: two
   }
 })()

Comment: Thanks for adding the minified file. The error is different to that displayed in your question, but the cause can clearly be seen. I'd suggest checking the code that created that output, and if it's syntactically valid, using a different minifier.